# how make active navigation if press "link"then button is white not grey here is code i try jsfiddle.net/egjg14fr/

Tags: javascript, php, web, navigation

I know there are many questions of this kind here, but I really don't know the reason why my code is not working. I'm trying to make a active navigation when click on link i need it to be white.
Here's demo.
[JS-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egjg14fr/)

```
         <div id="language" class="dropdown">
            <a href="#language" class="dropdown-toggle">Spēlē.lv</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="option"><a href="#"><img src="../TV3_Latvia_logo.png" width="60" height="60"></a></li>
        </ul>

  .dropdown {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    padding:5px;
    margin-right:10px;
    background:#ccc;
}
    .dropdown a:hover {
        display:block;
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#000;
        background:#fff;
    }

        .dropdown a {
        display:block;
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#333;
    }

    /* toggle */
    .dropdown .dropdown-toggle {
        padding:0;
    }

    /* dropdown */
    .dropdown-menu {
        position:absolute;
        top:100%;
        right:0;
        left:0;
        display:none;
        margin:0;
        padding:10px;
        list-style-type:none;
        background:#FFF;
            width:500px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px -4px #cacaca;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px -4px #cacaca;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px -4px #cacaca;

    }
        /* options */
        .dropdown-menu .option a {
            padding:5px;
            float:left;
        }
            .dropdown-menu .option a:hover {
                background-color:#999;
            }

    /* open */
    .dropdown-open {
        z-index:400;
    }
        .dropdown-open > .dropdown-menu {
            display:block;
        }
```

Comment: do not link other sites... put relevant code here. Only relevant ;)

Comment: ur fiddle is not working :(

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egjg14fr/).

Comment: check this : http://jsfiddle.net/egjg14fr/1/ is this correct ?

Comment: almost when hide submenu need back grey color

Answer (score 0):

See Updated [JS-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egjg14fr/2/) here.

You need to change  `.dropdown a:hover` to `.dropdown:hover`. so simple.